# set directory of tmpfile() on Linux

Tags: linux, posix, tmp, temporary-files

A program I use is failing when it uses [tmpfile()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/tmpfile) for large files. The problem seems to be I don't have permission to create large files in /tmp, which this function uses by default. So is there a way, perhaps with an environmental variable, that I can make tmpfile() write to a different location?

Edit: the program in question is [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/), which uses C.

Comment: It's unlikely that you " don't have permission to create large files in `/tmp`". It's more likely that you've filled up your `/tmp` partition. Why not simply increase the size of your `/tmp` partition?

Comment: This is on a shared server where I don't have control over /tmp settings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the environment variable TMPDIR to to tell tmpfile() where to create files:

sh syntax:

```
TMPDIR=/path/to/whatever; export TMPDIR
```

csh syntax:

```
setenv TMPDIR /path/to/whatever
```

Comment: This is plain **wrong**. tmpfile(3) does **not** respect the envirnoment variable TMPDIR, see also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38285068/7015849

Answer (score 1):

Given the information in [`man tmpfile (3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/tmpfile) you may want to: `#define P_tmpdir "/somedir"`
Of course, this probably isn't too reliable.

You can also set your environmental variable, `TMPDIR` to some location.

Comment: How are *my* preprocessor macros going to change what the C library does, exactly?