# std::tmpfile() not picking TMPDIR location

Tags: c++, c++11, temporary-files, tmp

I am using std::tmpfile() to create temporary files, but I want to use the location other than /tmp. I am exporting $TMPDIR to point to the new location, but std::tmpfile() doesn't pick the new location.

How to create temporary files with std::tmpfile() in a folder other than /tmp?

Comment: It is said that the Linux implementation actually unlinks the files so that they can't really be recovered from outside the /proc filesystem

Comment: Nowhere is it said that `tmpfile` will use such an environment variable. [The Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/tmpfile.3.html) says "Glibc will try the path prefix `P_tmpdir` defined in `<stdio.h>`", but that's all.

Comment: How can I set `P_tmpdir` location? and will that solve my problem?

Comment: What is the real problem you're trying to solve? Even if you would be able to get `std::tmpfile()` to store your file elsewhere, you still wouldn't be able to access other than through the returned `FILE *`, as glibc's implementation immediately deletes the file, relying on the OS to support reads from and writes to deleted files as long as you have a handle open.

Answer (score 1):

A quick test program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const char* tf = std::tmpnam(nullptr);
    std::cout << "tmpfile: " << tf << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

and an ltrace

```
osmith@osmith-VirtualBox:~$ ltrace ./test.exe
__libc_start_main(0x400836, 1, 0x7ffedf17e178, 0x4008e0 <unfinished ...>
_ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev(0x601171, 0xffff, 0x7ffedf17e188, 160)                  = 0
__cxa_atexit(0x400700, 0x601171, 0x601058, 0x7ffedf17df50)                      = 0
tmpnam(0, 0x7ffedf17e178, 0x7ffedf17e188, 192)                                  = 0x7fe4db5a0700
_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc(0x601060, 0x400965, -136, 0x7fe4db2d13d5) = 0x601060
_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc(0x601060, 0x7fe4db5a0700, 0x601060, 0xfbad2a84) = 0x601060
_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_c(0x601060, 10, 0x7fe4db91d988, 0x57474f44696b656ctmpfile: /tmp/filekiDOGW
) = 0x601060
_ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev(0x601171, 0, 0x400700, 0x7fe4db59fd10)                  = 0x7fe4db922880
+++ exited (status 0) +++
```

confirms that, per the man page, no environment variables are consulted by `std::tmpnam`, it only uses `P_tmpdir` which is a constant.

If this is purely for Linux, you could use `mkstemp` instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    char tmpl[] = "/var/tmp/testXXXXXX";
    int f = mkstemp(tmpl);
    if (f < 0) {
        std::cerr << "mkstemp failed\n";
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << tmpl << '\n';
    close(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Demo:

```
osmith@osmith-VirtualBox:~$ g++ -o test.exe test.cpp -std=c++14
osmith@osmith-VirtualBox:~$ ./test.exe
/var/tmp/testEFULD4
```